# eCryptfs With Mount Command Has Passphrase Cache?

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, ecryptfs, volume

Guys help me understand this!

I'm using **eCryptfs** with `mount` command to encrypt a single folder. In first time for setup the volume I run:

```bash
mount --types ecryptfs /path/to/.private /path/to/.private
```

So I choose the options.

For second time or any other after setup I run:

```bash
mount --types ecryptfs --options key=passphrase,ecryptfs_key_bytes=<bytes>,ecryptfs_cipher=<cipher>,ecryptfs_passthrough=no /path/to/.private /path/to/.private
```

So, when I do this steps directly in **command line** and I type a wrong password the volume are mounted but your content stay encrypted, works as expected but, when I put this steps inside a script even though I type a wrong password the content of volume are decrypted!

The **eCryptfs** has some cache for the passphrase? It some that I'm not knowledg?

PS: sorry for my english, I'm learning yet :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe eCryptFS normally uses the kernel keyring to store keys, so yes your keys could very well be getting cached in there.

If you just want to use eCryptFS for a single folder, consider just using it's `ecryptfs-mount-private` script. The lower level tools get progressively less user friendly IMO.

Some man pages to examine include ecryptfs, mount.ecryptfs, and mount.ecryptfs_private. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ECryptfs is great too.